# Failed bootstrap linked images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

On the page http://www.ams.org/wwtbam/wwtbam there are linked images that don't work on a mobile device.  See the heading Also See. The About the Game link works on a phone but the remaining image links such as Support the Game do not work.  They work fine in the webpage just not in a responsive environment.

Thanks for your help,

S.OBrien

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

> Just add **clearfix** class to the
>
> `<div class="col-md-6">`

under the

`<!-- Content Row -->`

as shown in the screenshot.

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1lte.png)

Comment: Hello Henrikh,  It worked! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out.  The code sample really helped.  Thanks again!